# Show jquery alert on ajax post timeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to create something which will report user that your $.post() request is timeouted . For that I am using

```
        // Set timeout for ajax request
        $.ajaxSetup({
           timeout: 5000 //5 Seconds to timeout
        });
```

`//when ajax request start show overlay
            $(document).ajaxStart(function(){
                $.blockUI({ css: { 
                    border: 'none', 
                    padding: '15px', 
                    backgroundColor: '#000', 
                    '-webkit-border-radius': '10px', 
                    '-moz-border-radius': '10px', 
                    opacity: .5,
                    'z-index':'15000',
                    color: '#fff' 
                } }); 
            }); 

            //when ajax request stops remove overlay    
            $(document).ajaxStop(function(){
                setTimeout($.unblockUI, 500); 
            });
    </pre>`

How to add javascript/jquery message in it to show that request is timeouted.

Answer (score 0):

For each individual ajax call, you can specify an error handler and one of the errors will be "timeout".  This is explained in the jQuery doc [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Or, you can set up a global [`$(document).ajaxError(fn)` handler](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/) and check the timeout error in just one place.

Keep in mind that you will not get timeout errors for JSONP ajax calls (because they use script tags).

Answer (score 0):

Use [ajaxError()](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/) handler to register a global error handler where you can use the `thrownError` to check whether it was because of timeout

```
$(document).ajaxError(function (event, jqXHR, options, thrownError) {
    if (thrownError== 'timeout') {
        alert('timedout')
    }
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/N6t2A/)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use [ajaxError](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxError/) to catch the failure and then use the thrownError and look for the errorcode for timeout (408  I believe).